# Missing X axis values on R plot

Tags: r, plot

Can someone tell me why this simple reproducible example yields missing values on the X axis?

`at` is supposed to put tick-marks from 1 to 20 right?

```
test <- iris[,3]
test <- test[1:20]
plot(test, type = "o", pch = 19)
axis(1, at=c(1:20), labels= c(1:20))
```

[image]

Comment: It is a scaling issue, if you zoom into the plot, each tick value is there.

Comment: Ah ah thanks... Maybe I shall delete this post...

Comment: You can use the `cex.axis` argument to scale down the axis label text if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dev.new()`

```
dev.new(width=10, height=10)
test <- iris[,3]
test <- test[1:20]
plot(test, type = "o", pch = 19)
axis(1, at=c(1:20), labels= c(1:20))
```

[image]